# MVC How to reaction to 2 different methods in one page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 methods : Add and Subtract. I want that when clicked Add button, the 3rd textbox displays the result of A + B; clicked "Subtract" button, the 3rd textbox displays the result of A - B.

I thought it should be a simple thing to do (because it can be done within a few lines of code in ASP.NET WebForm Application). But after trying many times and asked a few of friends, I still cannot find the solution...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "MyMVC"))
{
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.A)
        </li>
        <li><span>+ </span></li>
        <li>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.B)
        </li>
        <li><span>= </span></li>
        <li>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.C)
        </li>
    </ol>
    @{
    Html.RenderAction("Calculate", "MyMVC");
    }
    @{
    Html.RenderAction("Subtract", "MyMVC");
    }
}
```

Comment: No need of calling controller actions, you can do this easily by using `javascript`

Comment: @Karthik Hi Karthik, thx for your reply. But this practice is all about familiarizing myself with the MVC and Razor concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RenderAction tags aren't needed. The BeginForm extension also needs to render a form element that posts to itself.

Change your view to

```
@model SampleMvc.Models.SumModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.A)
        </li>
        <li><span>+ </span></li>
        <li>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.B)
        </li>
        <li><span>= </span></li>
        <li>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.C)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" id="add" name="Calculate" value="Add" />
    <input type="submit" id="subtract" name="Calculate" value="Subtract" />
}
```

Notice the name attribute on the submit inputs, this will enable the default model binder to bind to a property called Calculate.

For you View model use something similar to

```
public class SumModel {
        public int A { get; set; } 
        public int B { get; set; } 
        public int C { get; private set; }
        public string Calculate { get; set; }

        public void RunCalculation() {
            if (Calculate.Equals("add",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
                C = A + B;
            } else {
                C = A - B;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in the controller have actions similar to:

```
public ActionResult Calculate() {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Calculate(SumModel sumModel) {
    sumModel.RunCalculation();

    return View(sumModel);
}
```

When the form is submitted via the click events on the submit inputs the value of the button will be auto-magically bound to the Calculate property of the SumModel.

Then when the method RunCalculation is called it uses the property to work out which operation to run against the values A and B

Comment: Hi heads5150, I tried your solution, but it does not even run into the Claculate() method. My view is Index.cshtml, so I changed the Calculate method to Index(although I don't want to do so, as I want my method has a meaningful name rather than a name which is similar to the page). Then it does reach the method(Index(MyModel model)), but the C does not get updated.

Comment: @Franva In the action Index(MyModel model) place a breakpoint on model.RunCalculation(). I don't think you've implementated it properly, the code was tested before posting the answer. If you don't want Index(MyModel model) change it to PreferredName(MyMethod method) and then change Html.BeginForm() to Html.BeginForm("PreferredName","Home") assuming the action is on the HomeController

Comment: ,Hi heads5150, thank you for your explanation. I finally made it work by simply moving the Calculate property to the view as a parameter in the action based on your code. Thank you :) I also notice that MVC does not have a way to recognize more then one actions separately, so I need to add a flag variable in order to indicate which action I want to trigger. However,I want to write code into different methods without an extra flag variable. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Other easy approach is , you can have the same name for the buttons. and then read it in controller.

```
<input type="submit" id="add" name="buttonclicked" value="Add" />
<input type="submit" id="subtract" name="buttonclicked" value="Subtract" />


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string buttonclicked, SumModel sumModel) {
if(buttonclicked=="add"){

}
else{

}
}
```

Comment: hi arun. I am really glad to see your answer even I have chosen the answer for my question. There is not to many people who would like to answer a closed question. So I have to appreciate your willingness and I'll give it a try and let you know if I met any problems in your solution. Cheers :)